# How to create a new material and set it as active material using python script

Tags: python, scripting, materials, node-editor, shaders

How can I create a new material and set it active material on the active object using python script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
obj = bpy.context.object  # Select the active object.
mat = bpy.data.materials.new(name='Material')  # Create a material.
# Settings for the material go here.
obj.data.materials.append(mat)  # Assign the new material.
```

Comment: bpy.ops.material.new(name='zz') now gives me 'keyword "name" unrecognized' in blender 2.9